# pgAdmin4 + WSL2: can't see dbs created with other client

Tags: postgresql, windows-subsystem-for-linux, psql, pgadmin, wsl-2

I have followed the steps from [here](https://chloesun.medium.com/set-up-postgresql-on-wsl2-and-connect-to-postgresql-with-pgadmin-on-windows-ca7f0b7f38ab). I successfuly installed both postgres@12.8 in WSL2 and PGAdmin4 on Windows.
Once I start service in WSL and create a server connection in pgAdmin I am not able to see any databases create from the pgAdmin GUI or neither from psql client.

I tried to:

- set env variable `PGHOST` to `localhost`
- editing `postgresql.conf` to `listen_addresses = 'localhost'`
- connecting pgAdmin server by `localhost` name and by IP `127.0.0.1`

nothing works..

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue.

If you try to access your DB installed with pgAdmin from WSL 2, make sure you didnt install postgreSQL from Windows, as `sudo service postgresql start` from WSL will also start the only postgresql service you need.

Basically, it means you need to install postgresql ( `sudo apt-get install postgresql`) and start it **FROM WSL**, and then just open pgAdmin from Windows. Do NOT install postgresql directly on Windows as then your pgAdmin might create your DBs into the postgresql service started in Windows and not from the one started from WSL.

Make also sure that pgAdmin is installed for the same user that your WSL 2 uses, if you use it from VSCode for example. Otherwise, for the same reason, your WSL may not be able to find the corresponding DB.

Note that you can list the DB existing on a specific port by running `psql -p 5432 -l` from WSL ( change 5432 by the port you want to use ).